# Resource for Android Slight Left/Right Slide action on listview

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, action, slide

I am not sure if this question has been asked here or not. I look for a way to simulate the slide action in listview of Android. Similar to that of Samsung Galaxy/Nexus contact list actions.

As you can see from the below image I am sliding to the right and a different view is shown in place of the contact. (no number view)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) a nice post that may help you. Implementation may be a bit tricky, but that's a nice method of solving your problem IMHO. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is good and I did read it but as you can see from my above screenshot. I am looking to achieve the greeny bit in the middle not move the entire view. Kind of indicative of the action being performed.

Answer (score 2):

this [link](https://github.com/dharanikumar/IOS_7-SwipeGesture-Android) is very clear and useful

[image: image of this source code]

IOS 7 Swipe Gesture in Android listview. This repo provides listview swipe gesture pattern like IOS7 mailbox. messages to your Application.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I realize this action. We have a ListView lvSimple and we add onTouchListener to our lvSimple. This is my working code.

```
float historicX = Float.NaN, historicY = Float.NaN;
static final int DELTA = 50;
enum Direction {LEFT, RIGHT;}
...
ListView lvSimple = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.linLayout);
...
lvSimple.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (event.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            historicX = event.getX();
            historicY = event.getY();
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (event.getX() - historicX < -DELTA) 
            {
                FunctionDeleteRowWhenSlidingLeft();
                return true;
            }
            else if (event.getX() - historicX > DELTA)  
            {
                FunctionDeleteRowWhenSlidingRight();
                return true;
            } break;
            default: return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

where function FunctionDeleteRowWhenSlidingLeft() is calling when when we sliding to the left, FunctionDeleteRowWhenSlidingRight - to the right respectively. In this function you need paste code for animation.

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to Perform an action *On Swiping*:

> Check out **[SwipeActionAdapter](https://github.com/wdullaer/SwipeActionAdapter)**

It's an awesome library that allows Swipe in both directions with an underlying `Layout` or `Color`, and performs a desired action when the swipe/slide gesture is done. You can configure it to reveal/change the layout.

[image: Left Swipe]
[image: Right Swipe]

---

### If you want to swipe to *Reveal* actionable buttons:

> Check out [**SwipeMenuListView**](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView)

In a sense, it is more like the Swipe-able TableViews in iOS.

[image: SwipeMenuListView]
[image: SwipeMenuListView]
[image: SwipeMenuListView]