# Android - ListView slide left/right like Samsung contact ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, slide

I am developing an application, and I need a ListView like conctact ListView of my Samsung Galaxy S:

[image: img]

When I slide my finger to the right I can send message to this contact.

When I slide my finger to the right I can call to my contact.

I have my ListView and only need the function for do it...

Thanks in advance.

PD: 
I searched a lot and have not found anything. The most similar:
[Resource for Android Slight Left/Right Slide action on listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308836/resource-for-android-slight-left-right-slide-action-on-listview)

Comment: as follow we have a similar issue, and a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection

Comment: Were you able to show different colors on top of the list item as in the samsung contact application? If yes, please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: @Oliver can you post the complete working code

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you might what to do here is create a new view especially for the list view (call it ListViewFlinger or something). Then in this view, override its onTouchEvent method and place some code in there to determine a slide gesture. Once you have the slide gesture, fire a onSlideComplete event (you'll have to make that listener) an voialla, you a ListView with slide activated content.

```
float historicX = Float.NaN, historicY = Float.NaN;
static final TRIGGER_DELTA = 50; // Number of pixels to travel till trigger

@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    switch (e.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        historicX = e.getX();
        historicY = e.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (e.getX() - historicX > -TRIGGER_DELTA) {
            onSlideComplete(Direction.LEFT);
            return true;
        }
        else if (e.getX() - historicX > TRIGGER_DELTA)  {
            onSlideComplete(Direction.RIGHT);
            return true;
        } break;
    default:
        return super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }
}

enum Direction {
    LEFT, RIGHT;
}

interface OnSlideCompleteListener {
    void onSlideComplete(Direction dir);
}
```

Comment: Where i need to include the the call snippet code for making call, if i m gonna slide from left to right.

Comment: @Satheesh you place it in the view that you would like to scroll horizontally

Answer (score 29):

From another post, there was a link to this Google Code : https://gist.github.com/2980593
Which come from this Google+ post : https://plus.google.com/u/0/113735310430199015092/posts/Fgo1p5uWZLu .
This is a Swipe-To-Dismiss functionality.

From this you can provide your own Swipe-To-Action code. So here is my version, were I can personalize the left and right action and you can triggered the Dismiss animation (this is just a modification of Roman Nuric's code).

You have to include this class in your project :

```
public class SwipeListViewTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    // Cached ViewConfiguration and system-wide constant values
    private int mSlop;
    private int mMinFlingVelocity;
    private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
    private long mAnimationTime;

    // Fixed properties
    private ListView mListView;
    private OnSwipeCallback mCallback;
    private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero
    private boolean dismissLeft = true;
    private boolean dismissRight = true;

    // Transient properties
    private List < PendingSwipeData > mPendingSwipes = new ArrayList < PendingSwipeData > ();
    private int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
    private float mDownX;
    private boolean mSwiping;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
    private int mDownPosition;
    private View mDownView;
    private boolean mPaused;

    /**
     * The callback interface used by {@link SwipeListViewTouchListener} to inform its client
     * about a successful swipe of one or more list item positions.
     */
    public interface OnSwipeCallback {
        /**
         * Called when the user has swiped the list item to the left.
         *
         * @param listView               The originating {@link ListView}.
         * @param reverseSortedPositions An array of positions to dismiss, sorted in descending
         *                               order for convenience.
         */
        void onSwipeLeft(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);

        void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new swipe-to-action touch listener for the given list view.
     *
     * @param listView The list view whose items should be dismissable.
     * @param callback The callback to trigger when the user has indicated that she would like to
     *                 dismiss one or more list items.
     */
    public SwipeListViewTouchListener(ListView listView, OnSwipeCallback callback) {
        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(listView.getContext());
        mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
        mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
        mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
        mAnimationTime = listView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
        mListView = listView;
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new swipe-to-action touch listener for the given list view.
     * 
     * @param listView The list view whose items should be dismissable.
     * @param callback The callback to trigger when the user has indicated that she would like to
     *                 dismiss one or more list items.
     * @param dismissLeft set if the dismiss animation is up when the user swipe to the left
     * @param dismissRight set if the dismiss animation is up when the user swipe to the right
     * @see #SwipeListViewTouchListener(ListView, OnSwipeCallback, boolean, boolean)
     */
    public SwipeListViewTouchListener(ListView listView, OnSwipeCallback callback, boolean dismissLeft, boolean dismissRight) {
        this(listView, callback);
        this.dismissLeft = dismissLeft;
        this.dismissRight = dismissRight;
    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables (pauses or resumes) watching for swipe-to-dismiss gestures.
     *
     * @param enabled Whether or not to watch for gestures.
     */
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mPaused = !enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an {@link android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener} to be added to the
     * {@link ListView} using
     * {@link ListView#setOnScrollListener(android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener)}.
     * If a scroll listener is already assigned, the caller should still pass scroll changes
     * through to this listener. This will ensure that this
     * {@link SwipeListViewTouchListener} is paused during list view scrolling.</p>
     *
     * @see {@link SwipeListViewTouchListener}
     */
    public AbsListView.OnScrollListener makeScrollListener() {
        return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {@
            Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
                setEnabled(scrollState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL);
            }

            @
            Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
        };
    }

    @
    Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (mViewWidth < 2) {
            mViewWidth = mListView.getWidth();
        }

        switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                if (mPaused) {
                    return false;
                }

                // TODO: ensure this is a finger, and set a flag

                // Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                int childCount = mListView.getChildCount();
                int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
                mListView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
                int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
                int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
                View child;
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    child = mListView.getChildAt(i);
                    child.getHitRect(rect);
                    if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                        mDownView = child;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (mDownView != null) {
                    mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                    mDownPosition = mListView.getPositionForView(mDownView);

                    mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                }
                view.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return true;
            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    break;
                }

                float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(500); // 1000 by defaut but it was too much
                float velocityX = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity());
                float velocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
                boolean swipe = false;
                boolean swipeRight = false;

                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 2) {
                    swipe = true;
                    swipeRight = deltaX > 0;
                } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= velocityX && velocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity && velocityY < velocityX) {
                    swipe = true;
                    swipeRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
                }
                if (swipe) {
                    // sufficent swipe value
                    final View downView = mDownView; // mDownView gets null'd before animation ends
                    final int downPosition = mDownPosition;
                    final boolean toTheRight = swipeRight;
                    ++mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                    mDownView.animate()
                        .translationX(swipeRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
                        .alpha(0)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {@
                        Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            performSwipeAction(downView, downPosition, toTheRight, toTheRight ? dismissRight : dismissLeft);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // cancel
                    mDownView.animate()
                        .translationX(0)
                        .alpha(1)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(null);
                }
                mVelocityTracker = null;
                mDownX = 0;
                mDownView = null;
                mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                mSwiping = false;
                break;
            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused) {
                    break;
                }

                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop) {
                    mSwiping = true;
                    mListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                    // Cancel ListView's touch (un-highlighting the item)
                    MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
                    cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
                        (motionEvent.getActionIndex() << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                    mListView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                }

                if (mSwiping) {
                    mDownView.setTranslationX(deltaX);
                    mDownView.setAlpha(Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f,
                        1f - 2f * Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth)));
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    class PendingSwipeData implements Comparable < PendingSwipeData > {
        public int position;
        public View view;

        public PendingSwipeData(int position, View view) {
            this.position = position;
            this.view = view;
        }

        @
        Override
        public int compareTo(PendingSwipeData other) {
            // Sort by descending position
            return other.position - position;
        }
    }

    private void performSwipeAction(final View swipeView, final int swipePosition, boolean toTheRight, boolean dismiss) {
        // Animate the dismissed list item to zero-height and fire the dismiss callback when
        // all dismissed list item animations have completed. This triggers layout on each animation
        // frame; in the future we may want to do something smarter and more performant.

        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = swipeView.getLayoutParams();
        final int originalHeight = swipeView.getHeight();
        final boolean swipeRight = toTheRight;

        ValueAnimator animator;
        if (dismiss)
            animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);
        else
            animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, originalHeight - 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);


        animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {@
            Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
                    // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.
                    // Sort by descending position
                    Collections.sort(mPendingSwipes);

                    int[] swipePositions = new int[mPendingSwipes.size()];
                    for (int i = mPendingSwipes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        swipePositions[i] = mPendingSwipes.get(i).position;
                    }
                    if (swipeRight)
                        mCallback.onSwipeRight(mListView, swipePositions);
                    else
                        mCallback.onSwipeLeft(mListView, swipePositions);

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
                    for (PendingSwipeData pendingDismiss: mPendingSwipes) {
                        // Reset view presentation
                        pendingDismiss.view.setAlpha(1f);
                        pendingDismiss.view.setTranslationX(0);
                        lp = pendingDismiss.view.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.height = originalHeight;
                        pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    }

                    mPendingSwipes.clear();
                }
            }
        });

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {@
            Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                swipeView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });

        mPendingSwipes.add(new PendingSwipeData(swipePosition, swipeView));
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

From there, you can add the following code to your onCreate in the Activity with the ListView :

```
// Create a ListView-specific touch listener. ListViews are given special treatment because
// by default they handle touches for their list items... i.e. they're in charge of drawing
// the pressed state (the list selector), handling list item clicks, etc.
SwipeListViewTouchListener touchListener =
    new SwipeListViewTouchListener(
        listView,
        new SwipeListViewTouchListener.OnSwipeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft(ListView listView, int [] reverseSortedPositions) {
                //  Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "swipe left : pos="+reverseSortedPositions[0]);
                // TODO : YOUR CODE HERE FOR LEFT ACTION
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int [] reverseSortedPositions) {
                //  Log.i(ProfileMenuActivity.class.getClass().getName(), "swipe right : pos="+reverseSortedPositions[0]);
                // TODO : YOUR CODE HERE FOR RIGHT ACTION
            }
        },
        true, // example : left action = dismiss
        false); // example : right action without dismiss animation
listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
// Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during ListView scrolling,
// we don't look for swipes.
listView.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
```

Edit:
To add a color modification while swiping, your code must be in the `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` close to the `mDownView.setAlpha`.

Comment: do you know how to show color while swiping the view as in the samsung call application?

Comment: @SeanConnolly: I don't agree with our opinion - pasting helped me realize this is not that complex code. Furthermore the author references the actual author of the code. VERY useful post.

Comment: Very useful post! Do you know how to start different activities while swiping different litview items?

Comment: The adapter behind the ListView contains a list of Objects and those objects can provide (as an attribute of those objects) a reference to an activity. When swiping, reverseSortedPosition[0] contains the index of the list and thus the object corresponding to this index -> reference to a specific activity.

Comment: If I set OnClickListener to the cells of the ListView, the swipe is not working.

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to Perform an action *On Swiping*:

> Check out **[SwipeActionAdapter](https://github.com/wdullaer/SwipeActionAdapter)**

It's an awesome library that allows Swipe in both directions with an underlying `Layout` or `Color`, and performs a desired action when the swipe/slide gesture is done. You can configure it to reveal/change the layout.

~ *I haven't used the Samsung Contacts app, but sounds like this is what you want*

[image: Left Swipe]
[image: Right Swipe]

---

### If you want to swipe to *Reveal* actionable buttons:

> Check out [**SwipeMenuListView**](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView)

In a sense, it is more like the Swipe-able TableViews in iOS.

[image: SwipeMenuListView]
[image: SwipeMenuListView]
[image: SwipeMenuListView]