# How to start activities by swiping different listview items in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I am developing an application, and I need a ListView like contact ListView of Samsung Galaxy S

[image]

I could implement the swipe functionality with the help of [Android - ListView slide left/right like Samsung contact ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321016/android-listview-slide-left-right-like-samsung-contact-listview) post.

I need to start different activities when different listview items are swiped. Can anyone assist me? Any help is appreciated.

This is my listview activity.

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_listview);

    // Get ListView object from xml
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View",
            "Adapter implementation",
            "Simple List View In Android",
            "Create List View Android",
            "Android Example",
            "List View Source Code",
            "List View Array Adapter",
            "Android Example List View"
    };

    // Define a new Adapter
    // First parameter - Context
    // Second parameter - Layout for the row
    // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
    // Forth - the Array of data

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    // Create a ListView-specific touch listener. ListViews are given special treatment because by default they handle touches for their list items... i.e. they're in charge of drawing
   // the pressed state (the list selector), handling list item clicks, etc.
    SwipeListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeListViewTouchListener(
                    listView,
                    new SwipeListViewTouchListener.OnSwipeCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSwipeLeft(ListView listView, int [] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            //  Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "swipe left : pos="+reverseSortedPositions[0]);
                            // TODO : YOUR CODE HERE FOR LEFT ACTION
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int [] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            //  Log.i(ProfileMenuActivity.class.getClass().getName(), "swipe right : pos="+reverseSortedPositions[0]);
                            // TODO : YOUR CODE HERE FOR RIGHT ACTION

                        }
                    },
                    true, // example : left action = dismiss
                    false); // example : right action without dismiss animation
    listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
// Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during ListView scrolling,
// we don't look for swipes.
    listView.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
}}
```

This is my SwipeListViewTouchListener class.

```
public class SwipeListViewTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
// Cached ViewConfiguration and system-wide constant values
private int mSlop;
private int mMinFlingVelocity;
private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
private long mAnimationTime;

// Fixed properties
private ListView mListView;
private OnSwipeCallback mCallback;
private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero
private boolean dismissLeft = true;
private boolean dismissRight = true;

// Transient properties
private List< PendingSwipeData > mPendingSwipes = new ArrayList< PendingSwipeData >();
private int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
private float mDownX;
private boolean mSwiping;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
private int mDownPosition;
private View mDownView;
private boolean mPaused;

/**
 * The callback interface used by {@link SwipeListViewTouchListener} to inform its client
 * about a successful swipe of one or more list item positions.
 */
public interface OnSwipeCallback {
    /**
     * Called when the user has swiped the list item to the left.
     *
     * @param listView               The originating {@link ListView}.
     * @param reverseSortedPositions An array of positions to dismiss, sorted in descending
     *                               order for convenience.
     */
    void onSwipeLeft(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);

    void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);
}

/**
 * Constructs a new swipe-to-action touch listener for the given list view.
 *
 * @param listView The list view whose items should be dismissable.
 * @param callback The callback to trigger when the user has indicated that she would like to
 *                 dismiss one or more list items.
 */
public SwipeListViewTouchListener(ListView listView, OnSwipeCallback callback) {
    ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(listView.getContext());
    mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
    mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
    mAnimationTime = listView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
    mListView = listView;
    mCallback = callback;
}

/**
 * Constructs a new swipe-to-action touch listener for the given list view.
 *
 * @param listView The list view whose items should be dismissable.
 * @param callback The callback to trigger when the user has indicated that she would like to
 *                 dismiss one or more list items.
 * @param dismissLeft set if the dismiss animation is up when the user swipe to the left
 * @param dismissRight set if the dismiss animation is up when the user swipe to the right
 * @see #SwipeListViewTouchListener(ListView, OnSwipeCallback, boolean, boolean)
 */
public SwipeListViewTouchListener(ListView listView, OnSwipeCallback callback, boolean dismissLeft, boolean dismissRight) {
    this(listView, callback);
    this.dismissLeft = dismissLeft;
    this.dismissRight = dismissRight;
}

/**
 * Enables or disables (pauses or resumes) watching for swipe-to-dismiss gestures.
 *
 * @param enabled Whether or not to watch for gestures.
 */
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mPaused = !enabled;
}

/**
 * Returns an {@link android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener} to be added to the
 * {@link ListView} using
 * {@link ListView#setOnScrollListener(android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener)}.
 * If a scroll listener is already assigned, the caller should still pass scroll changes
 * through to this listener. This will ensure that this
 * {@link SwipeListViewTouchListener} is paused during list view scrolling.</p>
 *
 * @see {@link SwipeListViewTouchListener}
 */
public AbsListView.OnScrollListener makeScrollListener() {
    return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {@
                                                       Override
                                               public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
        setEnabled(scrollState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL);
    }

        @
                Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    };
}

@
        Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    if (mViewWidth < 2) {
        mViewWidth = mListView.getWidth();
    }

    switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            if (mPaused) {
                return false;
            }

            // TODO: ensure this is a finger, and set a flag

            // Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            int childCount = mListView.getChildCount();
            int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
            mListView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
            int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
            int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
            View child;
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                child = mListView.getChildAt(i);
                child.getHitRect(rect);
                if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                    mDownView = child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (mDownView != null) {
                mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                mDownPosition = mListView.getPositionForView(mDownView);

                mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            }
            view.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(500); // 1000 by defaut but it was too much
            float velocityX = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity());
            float velocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
            boolean swipe = false;
            boolean swipeRight = false;

            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 2) {
                swipe = true;
                swipeRight = deltaX > 0;
            } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= velocityX && velocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity && velocityY < velocityX) {
                swipe = true;
                swipeRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
            }
            if (swipe) {
                // sufficent swipe value
                final View downView = mDownView; // mDownView gets null'd before animation ends
                final int downPosition = mDownPosition;
                final boolean toTheRight = swipeRight;
                ++mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                mDownView.animate()
                        .translationX(swipeRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
                        .alpha(0)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {@
                                                                            Override
                                                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            performSwipeAction(downView, downPosition, toTheRight, toTheRight ? dismissRight : dismissLeft);
                        }
                        });
            } else {
                // cancel
                mDownView.animate()
                        .translationX(0)
                        .alpha(1)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(null);
            }
            mVelocityTracker = null;
            mDownX = 0;
            mDownView = null;
            mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
            mSwiping = false;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused) {
                break;
            }

            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop) {
                mSwiping = true;
                mListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                // Cancel ListView's touch (un-highlighting the item)
                MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
                cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
                        (motionEvent.getActionIndex() << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                mListView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
            }

            if (mSwiping) {
                mDownView.setTranslationX(deltaX);
                mDownView.setAlpha(Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f,
                        1f - 2f * Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth)));
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

class PendingSwipeData implements Comparable < PendingSwipeData > {
    public int position;
    public View view;

    public PendingSwipeData(int position, View view) {
        this.position = position;
        this.view = view;
    }

    @
            Override
    public int compareTo(PendingSwipeData other) {
        // Sort by descending position
        return other.position - position;
    }
}

private void performSwipeAction(final View swipeView, final int swipePosition, boolean toTheRight, boolean dismiss) {
    // Animate the dismissed list item to zero-height and fire the dismiss callback when
    // all dismissed list item animations have completed. This triggers layout on each animation
    // frame; in the future we may want to do something smarter and more performant.

    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = swipeView.getLayoutParams();
    final int originalHeight = swipeView.getHeight();
    final boolean swipeRight = toTheRight;

    ValueAnimator animator;
    if (dismiss)
        animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);
    else
        animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, originalHeight - 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);


    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {@
                                                                Override
                                                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
        if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
            // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.
            // Sort by descending position
            Collections.sort(mPendingSwipes);

            int[] swipePositions = new int[mPendingSwipes.size()];
            for (int i = mPendingSwipes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                swipePositions[i] = mPendingSwipes.get(i).position;
            }
            if (swipeRight)
                mCallback.onSwipeRight(mListView, swipePositions);
            else
                mCallback.onSwipeLeft(mListView, swipePositions);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
            for (PendingSwipeData pendingDismiss: mPendingSwipes) {
                // Reset view presentation
                pendingDismiss.view.setAlpha(1f);
                pendingDismiss.view.setTranslationX(0);
                lp = pendingDismiss.view.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = originalHeight;
                pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }

            mPendingSwipes.clear();
        }
    }
    });

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {@
                                                                                   Override
                                                                           public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        swipeView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
    });

    mPendingSwipes.add(new PendingSwipeData(swipePosition, swipeView));
    animator.start();
}}
```

Comment: I dont understand this "I need to start different activities when different listview items are swiped." you mean when you click on item start different activities?

Comment: So what's the problem exactly ? you want to know how to start an activity ?

Comment: when I swipe,
listview item 1 -> start Activity1
listview item 2 -> start Activity2
likewise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I tried the code out in Android Studio. Figured that in order for you to do a specific activity based on the swiped item, best way for you is be able to receive the position of the item that was swiped. So I checked the ***SwipeListViewTouchListener*** and found the specific part of the for ***performSwipeAction*** and noticed the parameter ***final int swipePosition*** and modified it...

```
    private void performSwipeAction(final View swipeView, final int swipePosition, boolean toTheRight, boolean dismiss) {
            // Animate the dismissed list item to zero-height and fire the dismiss callback when
            // all dismissed list item animations have completed. This triggers layout on each animation
            // frame; in the future we may want to do something smarter and more performant.

            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = swipeView.getLayoutParams();
            final int originalHeight = swipeView.getHeight();
            final boolean swipeRight = toTheRight;

            ValueAnimator animator;
            if (dismiss)
                animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);
            else
                animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, originalHeight - 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);


            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @
                        Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                    if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
                        // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.
                        // Sort by descending position
                        Collections.sort(mPendingSwipes);

                        int[] swipePositions = new int[mPendingSwipes.size()];
                        for (int i = mPendingSwipes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            swipePositions[i] = mPendingSwipes.get(i).position;
                        }
                        if (swipeRight) {
                            mCallback.onSwipeRight(mListView, swipePositions);
                            Log.d("SAMPLE", "SAMPLE IN SWIPE -- " + swipePosition);
                        }else {
Log.d("SAMPLE", "SAMPLE IN SWIPE -- " + swipePosition);
                            mCallback.onSwipeLeft(mListView, swipePositions);
                        }
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
                        for (PendingSwipeData pendingDismiss : mPendingSwipes) {
                            // Reset view presentation
                            pendingDismiss.view.setAlpha(1f);
                            pendingDismiss.view.setTranslationX(0);
                            lp = pendingDismiss.view.getLayoutParams();
                            lp.height = originalHeight;
                            pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        }

                        mPendingSwipes.clear();
                    }
                }
            });
```

And was able to receive the proper position for the listview item (0 for the topmost listview item, and so on). Now all you have to do is change the parameters in the callback -- adding the swipePosition, then using it to refer to the listviewitem and starting the activity based on that. :D Hope this helps you in some way. :)

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much for the guidance. I could able to modify the callback and start the activities based on the position.

Comment: @Lak No problem. Good luck with your app. :)